# Video Shortcode Only Returning a Link

Tags: shortcode, videos, video-player

I am trying to dynamically load a video in the media library using the built in MediaElement player. To do this, I am using the `do_shortcode()` function to run the `[video]` shortcode and build up the necessary divs and such.

However, no matter what I do, the `do_shortcode()` with `[video]` only returns a href link and not the video player. Any suggestions?

```
<?php echo do_shortcode("[video src= 'link_to_my_video.mp4 ']"); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress has this little minimally documented function, [`wp_video_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_video_shortcode)

Just pass an array with the necessary information as if you were writing out the shortcode.